# Is breakfast the most important meal of the day?

Tags: nutrition, diet, fasting

Everyone has heard the saying that "breakfast is the most important meal of the day" and thus "you should never skip breakfast".

Is there any evidance of this? Are there any benefits of breakfast vs other meals?

I've fasted for days before and it doesn't really seem to affect my ability to perform physically or mentally, so I doubt a dinner -> lunch fast would have any effect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here unless directly related to medical treatment. Please see https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Gary Gregory. In which stackexchange community can one ask such a question?

Comment: @CareyGregory If diet and nutrition are off-topic here, how is it that the tags for both of these exist here?

Comment: @Polyhat Almost anyone can create tags. Their existence says nothing about site policy.